# Rails Tutorial Chapter 7, Exercise 4

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm having trouble with Exercise 4 in Chapter 7 of [railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#sec%3asignup_exercises).

Here are the tests:

```
    describe "signup" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button "Create my Account".not_to change(User, :count) }
        end
    end

    describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign up") }
        it { should have_content('error') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            fill_in "Name", with: "Example User"
            fill_in "Email", with: "user@example.com"
            fill_in "Password", with: "foobar"
            fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
        end

        it "should create a user" do
            expect do
                click_button "Create my account"
            end.to change(User, :count).by(1)
        end
    end

    describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button "Create my account" }
        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
    end
end
```

Here is what it's supposed to test, users_controller.rb:

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
  flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
  redirect_to @user
 else
    render 'new'
 end
end
```

Here's the show.html.erb code as well:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="span4">
    <section>
        <h1>
            <%= gravatar_for @user %>
            <%= @user.name %>
        </h1>
    </section>
</aside>
</div>
```

When I run my tests, I get this:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb 
........FF

Failures:

  1) User Pages signup after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User Pages signup after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
   expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.86152 seconds
10 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:57 # User Pages signup after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58 # User Pages signup after saving the user
```

It should save the test user to the test db, but for some reason, user.name is turning out nil. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without going over your code in detail to understand the context of everything, it's not that `user.name` is returning `nil`, it's that `user` is `nil`, and therefore has no method/property `name` as seen here:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

You have this line here before the test case defining the symbol `:user`:

```
let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }
```

yet you reference the object `user` in your test:

```
it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
```

Change the symbol `:user` to `user` in the former and your tests should pass.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I figured it out. the "after saving the user" do end block was outside of the scope of the "with valid information" block, and thus the form wasn't getting filled in (which is where nil's coming from). I put the "after saving the user block" inside of "with valid information" block, and the test passed. Just for replying I'll mark your answer as accepted. :-)

Comment: Ah, well feel free to write that in an answer and accept your own so that if someone else stumbles on this same problem they know where they're going wrong :)

Comment: You're right that the problem is a nil `user` and not a nil `user.name`, but the proposed solution isn't right. Using the symbol `:user` in the `let` automatically creates a local variable called `user`. See the [Rails Tutorial sample app reference implementation](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed) for more information.

The problem is probably that a user with email `user@example.com` somehow isn't getting created by the `click_button` command. I don't know why that would be, but as a workaround you could just hard-code the name, replacing `user.name` with `"Example User"`.

Comment: Of course, if you hard-code the name, you will no longer need the `user.name`, and hence you won't need the `let`.

Comment: None of this explains why the other test isn't passing. Check the behavior in the browser to verify that the `success` flash message appears.